# Populate Inputs in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Trying to pass in a value for a input in a form seems to yield no results. The documentation for the [helper inputText](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputText.scala.html) shows a value option as a part of the creation of the input, but I am not sure how to pass in the desired parameters to the constructor.

I am passing in the parameters as follows:

```
@inputText(accountForm("accountName"), args = '_label -> "Account Name: ", '_value -> "Test")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` parameter you see in the helper `inputText` comes from the [`Field`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L509) class. If you  want to give your field a default value, you have to set the value in your Controller. You can set default values by using the [`fill`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L268) method from the `Form` class.

Note: there is also the [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp). You can pass this attribute with the inputText helper: `@inputText(accountForm("accountName"), 'placeholder -> "Test")`

Answer (score 11):

You can fill in the `Form` class as suggested by Li-o or can override the form value in the template itself like this. This will set it to "Test" or the value of "variable".

```
@inputText(accountForm("accountName").copy(value=Some("Test")), args = '_label -> "Account Name: ")
@inputText(accountForm("accountName").copy(value=Some(variable)), args = '_label -> "Account Name: ")
```

Comment: I think the syntax could be something like this: `accountForm("accountName").copy(value= Option[String]("Test"))`